# Fitting 4 triangles within a background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, theming

I'm trying to fit 4 triangles in a master template using jquery, html5 and canvas,

I can't seem to make them fit...

Here is what I got so far...

https://jsfiddle.net/ax67r91y/

The code I think is wrong:

```
ctx.drawImage(part.img,                             // random image 
    0, 0, part.w, part.h,                           // source
    part.x,part.y,part.trisize.w,part.trisize.h);   // destination
```

All images should be cut down into 2 forms: a " v " and a " ^ ",

I can move images, but shrinking them to the correct size seems unattainable...

I think I'm close, but it's been hours I'm on this, help is welcome!!!

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to guess, how exactly you want them to look like. Maybe you could provide something like a reference image of the way you want them to be arranged?

Comment: Added image as per requested.

Comment: At the moment, you are using images to insert the background color. You can do that with plain js. Would that be preferable for you?

Comment: I don`t want background color, I need images, the images shown are for debugging only, could you please help with image cropping, scaling and positioning?

Comment: I've fixed it to this: https://jsfiddle.net/ax67r91y/2/. Now you need to fix the wrong coordinates (there are wrong `x`,`y` and `w`, `h` values) and then reenable the overlay. The main mistake was that you were defining the coordinates relative to the image size, not the trisize. Ask, if you want more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function createSVG(name, attributes) {
 var svg_node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", name);

 Object.keys(attributes).forEach(function(key) {
  if (key == 'textContent') {
   svg_node.textContent = attributes[key];
   return;
  } 
  svg_node.setAttribute(key, attributes[key]);
 });


 return svg_node;
}

Element.prototype.appendSVG = function(name, attributes) {
 this.appendChild(createSVG(name, attributes));
}

function Polygons() {
 this.canvas = createSVG('svg', {
  'version':    '1.1',
  'shape-rendering':  'geometricPrecision',
  'viewBox':    '0 0 1589 745',
    'class': 'svg-content',
 });
  this.defs = createSVG('defs', {});
  this.canvas.appendChild(this.defs);
  this.registerPatterns();
 
  this.drawInnerLayer();
 this.drawOuterLayer();
}

Polygons.prototype.registerPatterns = function() {
 var patternBottom = createSVG('pattern', {
   'height': "100%",
    'width': "100%",
    'patternContentUnits': "objectBoundingBox",
    'viewBox': "0 0 1 1",
    'preserveAspectRatio': "xMidYMid slice",
  });
  var imgBottom = createSVG('image', {
   'height': "1",
    'width': "1",
    'preserveAspectRatio': "xMidYMid slice",
  });
  var imgLeft = imgBottom.cloneNode(true)
  imgLeft.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', "http://waw.wizard.build/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/TMP/1.png");
  var imgMiddle = imgBottom.cloneNode(true);
  imgMiddle.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', "http://waw.wizard.build/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/TMP/2.png");
  var imgRight = imgBottom.cloneNode(true);
  imgRight.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', "http://waw.wizard.build/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/TMP/3.png");
  
  imgBottom.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', "http://waw.wizard.build/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/TMP/4.png");
  
  var patternLeft = patternBottom.cloneNode(true);
  patternLeft.setAttribute('id', "img-left");
  patternLeft.appendChild(imgLeft);
  var patternRight = patternBottom.cloneNode(true);
  patternRight.setAttribute('id', "img-right");
  patternRight.appendChild(imgRight);
  var patternMiddle = patternBottom.cloneNode(true);
  patternMiddle.setAttribute('id', "img-middle");
  patternMiddle.appendChild(imgMiddle);
  
  patternBottom.setAttribute('id', "img-bottom");
  patternBottom.appendChild(imgBottom);
  
  this.defs.appendChild(patternLeft);
  this.defs.appendChild(patternRight);
  this.defs.appendChild(patternMiddle);
  this.defs.appendChild(patternBottom);
  
 var patternOverlayer = createSVG('pattern', {
   'height': "100%",
    'width': "100%",
    'patternContentUnits': "objectBoundingBox",
    'id': "img-overlayer",
  });
  var imgOverlayer = createSVG('image', {
   'height': "1",
    'width': "1",
    'preserveAspectRatio': "none",
  });
  imgOverlayer.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href', "http://waw.wizard.build/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/frame-all.png");
  patternOverlayer.appendChild(imgOverlayer);
  this.defs.appendChild(patternOverlayer);
}


Polygons.prototype.drawOuterLayer = function() {
 this.canvas.appendSVG('rect', {
  'x': '0',
    'y': '0',
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%',
    'fill': 'url(#img-overlayer)',
  'class':   'img-overlayer',
 });
}

Polygons.prototype.drawInnerLayer = function() {
 this.canvas.appendSVG('polygon', {
  'points':   '500,55 800,50 643,370', 
  'class':   'inner-polygon polygon-left',
    'fill': 'url(#img-left)',
 });
 this.canvas.appendSVG('polygon', {
  'points':   '800,70 665,395 935,395', 
  'class':   'inner-polygon polygon-middle',
    'fill': 'url(#img-middle)',
 });
 this.canvas.appendSVG('polygon', {
  'points':   '820,50 1115,45 950,375', 
  'class':   'inner-polygon polygon-right',
    'fill': 'url(#img-right)',
 });
 this.canvas.appendSVG('polygon', {
  'points':   '660,415 940,415 805,720', 
  'class':   'inner-polygon polygon-down',
    'fill': 'url(#img-bottom)',
 });
}

var polygons = new Polygons();
document.getElementById('svg-container').appendChild(polygons.canvas);
```

```css
#svg-container { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 100%; 
 vertical-align: middle; 
 overflow: hidden; 
}

.svg-content { 
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container"></div>
```